# How is Wireshark able to capture multicast traffic without joining the multicast group

Tags: multicast, hyper-v

If I understood correctly, in multicast scenario, packets send to a multicast group are received only by the clients who joined the group(essentially the router forwards the packets **ONLY** to intended recipients). Then how is wireshark able to capture the multicast traffic(even in non promiscuous mode)?

Please help me understand if I am missing something.  In the below sample capture, 192.168.1.1 is the server sending the multicast packets to group 239.0.0.222 and the current machine/wireshark did not join the group but still be able to capture the packets.

Topology:
I have 3 VMs, 1 Server, 1 Client and 1 WireShark VM. All of these three VMs are behind a Hyper-V Private switch(in the same subnet).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that routers will only forward multicast traffic if there are clients on the other side that are expecting that traffic.  But in your case all 3 VMs are in the same subnet so there's no router involved, only a switch.

The switch that the 3 VMs are connected to probably doesn't perform any special handing of multicast messages.  This means that any multicast message it receives is being sent out on all ports, which includes the VM running Wireshark.  And because the packets are physically arriving on that port, Wireshark sees them and displays them.